# How to create a second docker file, if necessary?

Tags: linux, docker, github-actions

Comrades, help with the creation of the second Dockerfile. My main project is to execute the command `/bin/ss -tulpn`, an `iproute2` package that checks for open ports. I came to the conclusion that I need a second Dockerfile, since one file is needed to create a local `python 3 -m http.server` server, and the other file checks the ports with the `/bin/ss -tulpn` command.

How can I better implement this?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iproute2 && apt-get install -y python3

RUN mkdir /output

CMD nohup python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 9000 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
CMD /bin/ss -tulpn > /output/result.txt
```

**build.yml**

```yaml
name: Build and Package

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      build-input:
        description: 'optional_input'     
        required: false
        default: 'optional_input' # does nothing now but could be useful later

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build and run Docker container
      run: |
        docker build -t mycontainer .
        docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/output mycontainer
        
    - name: Change permissions
      run: |
        sudo chmod -R 777 output/
        
    - name: Create artifact
      run: |
        cd output
        tar -cvzf result.tar.gz result.txt
        mv result.txt result.deb
      if: always()

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: result-artifact
        path: output/result.tar.gz
```

**docker.yml**

```yaml
name: Example Workflow

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      build-input:
        description: 'optional_input'     
        required: false
        default: 'optional_input' # does nothing now but could be useful later

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build and run Docker container
      run: |
        docker build -t mycontainer .
        docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/output mycontainer
```

I tried to run on the same docker file and server in the background:

```
nohup python 3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 9000 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and the `/bin/ss -tulpn` command itself, but the program still did not issue ports. And if not in the background, using `python 3 -m http.server` in the decor, then the program freezes due to server operation and that's it, the end.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? What do you want to do? From the look of it, you can avoid Dockerfile completely and run those two command directly in a `run`.

Comment: A Docker container only runs one command, and it needs to be a foreground process.  Can you just set `CMD python -m http.server`, without the `nohup` invocation?  What exactly does `ss` do here; can it be in a separate container (maybe based on the same image)?